# Compare two data sets in Tableau

Tags: database, data-visualization, tableau-api, reporting, data-warehouse

I am new to tableau.I want to create a dashboard with the following requirement. 
In the source table, there are three different status('OK','SU','TX') for a particular product in a particular day. The status column overwrites with the new status when the status gets change. I want to create a report that shows the product Id, previous day status(if the previous day status='TX'or 'SU') and today status. Should I maintain a separate table for the above requirement or is there any other method in tableau?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is overwritten then it's gone. Therefore, if you want to know the status of the previous day, you'll need to keep the previous day data somewhere.

Tableau isn't a database, it's a visualisation layer, so the data should be stored elsewhere and fed into Tableau to create your dashboard.